Let $\lambda$ be a circle with $-1,1\in \lambda$, $z_1, z_2\not\in\lambda$ and $z_1 z_2=1$ , only one of $z_1, z_2$ in the interior of $\lambda$.

Let $\lambda$ be a circle with $-1,1\in \lambda$, $z_1, z_2\not\in\lambda$ and $z_1 z_2=1$ , show that $z_1, z_2$ has one and only one in the interior of $\lambda$.

If $\lambda$ is just the unit circle, it is OK. For general circle, how to do then? Conformly transformed to be the unit circle, but $f(z_1)f(z_2)$ need not be $1$...Oh.

An easy way to see it is to notice that the center of the circle is at $(0,a)$ and the equation is $x^2+y^2-2ay=1$. But now if $z_1=(u,v)$ it follows that $1/z_1=(\frac{u}{u^2+v^2}, -\frac{v}{u^2+v^2})$ so if $f(z)=x^2+y^2-2ay, z=(x,y)$ we have $f(1/z_1)=\frac{1+2av}{u^2+v^2}$ while $f(z_1)=u^2+v^2-2av$ so $(f(z_1)-1)(f(1/z_1)-1)=-\frac{(u^2+v^2-2av-1)^2}{u^2+v^2}<0$ as long as $f(z_1) \ne 1$ which holds by hypothesis since $z_1$ is not on the circle. So one of $f(z_1)-1, f(1/z_1)-1$ is positive and one negative which means precisely that one of $z_1, 1/z_1$ is inside and one outside the given circle.
